# Access variable in the forms class?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

How to get the value of ModelChoiceField in Django forms class.
I have one ModelChoiceField in my forms.ModelForm class:

```
class mStockForm(forms.ModelForm):

      mStock_product = forms.ModelChoiceField(
                          queryset=mProduct.objects.filter(),
                          label='Select Milk Product',
                          help_text="Choose from the list of milk products",
                          required=True,
)



 #---------------------------Want to access 
    mStock_Product'''''''''''''''''''''''#
    value = mStock_product.value   #<------------Here
```

Comment: What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: Just need to access ModelChoiseFiled vale in the same class in which it is defined value = mStock_product.value

Comment: For what **reason** do you want to do that? feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: When someone selects the ModelChoise then I want to fetch the relevant data from the model according to select choices

Comment: Do you perhaps want to make a dependent drop down?

Comment: yes , I want o select another model according to this choice. in another word I want and on Change Event from this dropdown like javascript has

Answer (score 0):

***Your question is not clear. But let me try to answer.***

There are different approaches for you need. You can create a simple endpoint and use JS to create the dynamic choice field.

Try to look [Django Rest Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/). It is a high-class approach for creating API for your projects. With help of this framework, you can create endpoints in minutes.

After creating a simple endpoint you can use JavaScript (**Fetch API or jQuery Ajax**) to fetch related data from the endpoint to your form.

See: [How to Implement Dependent/Chained Dropdown List with Django](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html)